# How to stop getting back to "blank" in the form after alert?

Tags: javascript, html

Alert pop up if there is a blank in forms.
The error check in Javascript is working,
but after alert is closed, the text in the form will be blank.

I want that the text I filled in will stay after alert is closed.
Because I want to fill up the only blank after alert.

Could you let me know how to keep the value even after alert?

```js
function check_form() {
  let name = document.form1.name.value;
  let mail = document.form1.mail.value;
  let subject = document.form1.subject.value;
  let message = document.form1.message.value;

  let error_message = '';

  if (name == '') {
    error_message += 'Name is blank\n';
  }
  if (mail == '') {
    error_message += 'Mail is blank\n';
  }
  if (subject == '') {
    error_message += 'Subject is blank\n';
  }
  if (message == '') {
    error_message += 'Message is blank\n';
  }

  if (error_message != '') {
    alert(error_message);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="check_form()">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

  <label for="mail">Mail</label>
  <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail">

  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">

  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Send message" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your form is submitted when the alert pops up, the `return false` is not enough to stop the form submit. You should use the `preventDefault` in order to stop the submit in the error case

```js
function check_form(e) {
  let name = document.form1.name.value;
  let mail = document.form1.mail.value;
  let subject = document.form1.subject.value;
  let message = document.form1.message.value;

  let error_message = '';

  if (name == '') {
    error_message += 'Name is blank\n';
  }
  if (mail == '') {
    error_message += 'Mail is blank\n';
  }
  if (subject == '') {
    error_message += 'Subject is blank\n';
  }
  if (message == '') {
    error_message += 'Message is blank\n';
  }

  if (error_message != '') {
    alert(error_message);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="check_form(event)">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

  <label for="mail">Mail</label>
  <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail">

  <label for="subject">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject">

  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

  <input type="submit" value="Send message" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```